# Use plug man to install a phone gap plugin iOs

Tags: ios, cordova, plugman

am having a tuff time integrating a bar code plugin into my cordova project using plug man. I went through the plug man documentation and followed what the command which they suggested ie.

Syntax:
plugman install --platform  --project  --plugin  [--variable NAME=VALUE]

My Example: 
plugman install --platform iOS --project ~/Users/gundalasubbareddy/Desktop/BarCodeReader --plugin ~/Users/gundalasubbareddy/Downloads/BarcodeScanner-master

The output what i get is this:

## Usage

### Install a plugin

```
$ plugman install --platform <platform> --project <directory> --plugin <plugin> [--variable NAME=VALUE]
```

Parameters:

- platform : One of android, ios, blackberry10, wp7 or wp8
- project : Path reference to a cordova-generated project of the platform you specify
- plugin : One of a path reference to a local copy of a plugin, or a remote https: or git: URL pointing to a cordova plugin (optionally append #branch:subdir) or a plugin ID from http://plugins.cordova.io
- variable NAME=VALUE: Some plugins require install-time variables to be defined. These could be things like API keys/tokens or other app-specific variables.

### Uninstall a plugin

```
$ plugman uninstall --platform <platform> --project <directory> --plugin <plugin-id>
```

Parameters:
 - plugin : The plugin to remove, identified by its id (see the plugin.xml's  attribute)

### Optional parameters

- www : www assets for the plugin will be installed into this directory. Default is to install into the standard www directory for the platform specified
- plugins_dir : a copy of the plugin will be stored in this directory. Default is to install into the /plugins folder
- searchpath : a directory to look in for a plugin with the provided ID before looking on http://plugins.cordova.io
  Use the searchpath flag multiple times to specify several directories (searched in order). The search is not recursive and will only look one level down.

### Optional flags

--debug|-d    : Verbose mode

--help|-h     : Displays this message

--version|-v  : Displays version

## Interacting with the registry

### Add a user account

```
$ plugman adduser
```

### Publish a plugin

```
$ plugman publish <directory>
```

### Unpublish a plugin

```
$ plugman unpublish <name>@<version>
```

### Search for a plugin

```
$ plugman search <keyword1 keyword2 ...>
```

### Display plugin information

```
$ plugman info plugin
```

### Manage registry configuration

```
$ plugman config set registry http://localhost:5984/registry/_design/app/_rewrite
$ plugman config get registry
```

### Manage owners

```
$ plugman owner ls org.apache.cordova.core.file
$ plugman owner add username org.apache.cordova.core.file
$ plugman owner rm username org.apache.cordova.core.file
```

I don't see the plugin installed into my project. Please help me where am i doing wrong. 
Thanks
santosh

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Fixed now, I had a typo in 'platform'. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the fact that 'iOS' should be 'ios'.

So change your line to:

```
plugman install --platform ios --project ~/Users/gundalasubbareddy/Desktop/BarCodeReader --plugin ~/Users/gundalasubbareddy/Downloads/BarcodeScanner-master
```